# Importing bash scripts and exporting variables

Tags: bash, scripting, git-bash

I have the following setup of bash files:

- main.sh (it accepts parameters, e.g. ./main.sh -b var1 -- --param1=val1 --param2=val2)
- params.sh (it handles all params, i.g. param1, param2)
- file1.sh (one file that it's called by main.sh)
- file2.sh (one file that it's called by main.sh)

one example of file1.sh, file2.sh is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -em

source params.sh
#do something
```

However in some cases, I call from file2.sh the file1.sh. Having a large number of files1,2,3... and many times calling one the other, due to the `source params` this toolset I have created has become really slow. Further more I have noticed in git bash, that "bash.exe:ID" it opens a lot of files which add even more slowness.

Is there any way to achieve the followin:

1. Having the params.sh to handle all the params of the main.sh
2. All files to be able to see all the params
3. to improve the speed

Comment: refactor so you need only `source params.sh` once from `main.sh` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

As a general concept you could export a flag to remember that param.sh was already called. Something like `export PARAMS_INITIALIZED=1` and check it in the beginning of param.sh to not execute it again and again. (well known as include guards in the C programming language)

This assumes that it is not necessary to execute param.sh again and again. It appears to be some kind of option parser so it shouldn't be necessary. Just `export` what you set in param.sh and it is available in the other scripts called later.

For the slowness. Without any code how could we know what's slow. For Bash on Windows calling external commands is very slow and should be avoided anywhere possible.

Comment: Actually I'm using something like export PARAMS_INITIALIZED=$(getParam "--param") && $(removeParam "-param"). I've noticed in general that something like doesn't work properly. What you have is a fixed value, which is much easier

Comment: Your approach probably doesn't work because `$( )` executes in a subshell and cannot influence the remaining script.

Comment: The slowness is due to the fact that with file1,file2, file3 etc I was using source params.sh on every file and due to $() it was getting really slow. Now it works much better!